# label over specific cells (index) in imagesc

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created this map of Jamaica using matrix `A`. I want to insert text labels on this image at specific indexes for cities. For Example `kingston` on this map is at point `15, 38`, where `15` is the `row` and `38` the `column`, this point I would label "kingston". My matrix is below and the image of it generated from `imagesc` is below as well. I was playing around with `get(gca, 'position')` but that was not successful.

```
% Cities
kingston = [15 38];
montegoBay = [4 15];
portRoyal = [18 31];
stThomas = [10 55];
mandeville = [13 21];
ochoRios = [2 29];

A = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1; 
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 3 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 3 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 3 3 3 0 3 0 3 3 3 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 3 3 0 3 3 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 3 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 3 3 3 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 3 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 3 3 3 0 0 3 3 0 3 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 0 3 0 3 3 0 0 0 3 3 3 0 3 0 3 3 3 3 3 0 3 3 3 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1;
 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 0 3 0 3 3 0 0 3 3 3 0 0 3 0 0 3 0 3 3 0 3 0 3 0 1;
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 0 3 3 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 3 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1; 
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 3 0 3 0 3 3 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 0 3 0 1 1 1 1 1 3 0 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 0 3 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];

Cmap = [1 1 1; 0 0 1; 0 1 0];
colormap(Cmap);
imagesc(A);
axis off
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the function [text](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) like this:

```
text(38,15,'kingston')
```

i.e. in opposite order, because your axis is in i-j direction, and not x-y (try typing `axis xy` to see what I mean).

[image: kingston]

(I have changed the font size to 15: `text(38,15,'kingston','FontSize',15)`)

If you want to go a step further, define your cities as a cell array:

```
Cities = {'kingston','montegoBay','portRoyal','stThomas','mandeville','ochoRios'};
```

and their location in a matrix:

```
location = [15 38;
    4 15;
    18 31;
    10 55;
    13 21;
    2 29];
```

And then all you need is one text command:

```
text(location(:,2),location(:,1),Cities,'FontSize',12)
```

to get the final result:

[image: all cities]

Comment: I was actually using the `text(x,y,'labelname')`, but I was putting it before the `imagesc`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text` function to do that as:

```
text(x,y,'MyText')
```

See the documentation for more info:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html

Hope it helps.